# Extension Gmail Notifier requires Goa, Soup, Gio typelibs

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I tried to install [Gmail Notify](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/154/gmail-notify/) on GNOME 3 but it was not working. When I click over the icon, it  says

> "Extension requires Goa, Soup, Gio typelibs".

What does it mean? How can I fix this and get Gmail Notify working?

**My configuration** 
Ubuntu 11.10, GNOME Shell 3.2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the libraries `gir1.2-soup`, `gir1.2-goa`, and `gir1.2-glib`.

Just do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-soup gir1.2-goa gir1.2-glib
```

Also, don't forget to add your Gmail account into "Online Accounts".

---

In case you're using 12.04, an anonymous user suggested the following:

> On 12.04 I found that after installing the pre-requisites above, you
>   had to:
>
> 1. Go to the Installed Extensions page, https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and click on the (X) to remove
>      gmail notifier.
> 2. Install it again from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/154/gmail-notify/ by setting
>      the slider to "on"